# list of radiobutton lists - only allow one to be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple radiobutton lists within a fieldset tag.

I only ever want one item to be selectable from the whole list...
currently i can select one item from each radio button list - which is normal

I know the proper way would to do this would be to have one long radio button list, but that is not an option.

Is there a way in javascript/jquery that given the fieldset class name - say

`<fieldset class="mylistofradiolists">` that when a radio button within it is selected all other items are **deselected** and only that **single one remains selected**

Thanks

Comment: you can use the same name for all the radio button inside one fieldset

Comment: @MiqdadAli "I know the proper way would to do this would be to have one long radio button list, but that is not an option." He's already said that's not possible, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with the following code

```
$radios =  $('.mylistofradiolists :radio');
$radios.on('change',function(){
   $radios.not(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

When an radio is selected all other radio's except that are deselected within that container.

It's better to use

```
$radios =  $('.mylistofradiolists [type=radio]');
```

Instead of

```
$radios =  $('.mylistofradiolists :radio');
```

As the doc for [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector says

> Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
> specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the
> performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
> method.
>
> **For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"]**
> instead.

Comment: isn't that browser's default action?

Comment: @undefined, yes it is, if all the radio's have the same name. But in this case they doesn't. I am assuming he is using different names for radio groups as he mentioned `radio button list`

Comment: @undefined Why is it unreasonable? From a user view point, there's nothing different from what they're used to - only being able to select one option from a list.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I said that based on the radio buttons default behavior. that can be done without using jQuery. okay.

Comment: @undefined I agree, the preferable solution would be to render all of the radios with the same `name` attribute, and let the browser handle it. However, the question indicates this isn't a potential solution, though it doesn't say why. One possible reason would be the HTML being rendered by server-side code that they don't have the ability to modify.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist in that case I agree.

Comment: @everyone - yes i realise that this is a hack, but i am restricted by a form builder. this solution works for me. thanks

Comment: @raklos, sorry, missed the spaces while re-formatting. Updated check now.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the functionality of selecting only one radio button from list of radio buttons which are seperated by fieldset tag by keeping each "name" attribute of the radio button same.

e.g :- for first field set - keeping the radio button name field same.

```
<fieldset >
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Italian<br />
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Greek<br />
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Chinese<br />
<fieldset >
```

and for second fieldset , keeping the name attribute same :-

```
<fieldset >
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : Indian<br />
<input type="radio" name="food" /> : UK<br />
<fieldset >
```

Hope this anser user question :)

Comment: He's already stated in the question that he can't do this: "I know the proper way would to do this would be to have one long radio button list, but that is not an option."